# Running Java Applet gives me Error: Click for details

Tags: java, applet

I am learning Java and have created a simple applet
Here is my HelloWorld.java code

```
import java.applet.*;  
import java.awt.*;  
public class HelloWorld extends Applet  {
     public void init() 
     { 

     } 
     public void stop() 
     { 

     } 

     public void paint(Graphics g) 
     { 
       g.drawString("Hey hey hey",20,20); 
      g.drawString("Hellooow World",20,40); 

     }  
}
```

Here is my html code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My First Java Applet</title>
</head>
<body>
Here's my first Java Applet:<br /><br />
<applet code="HelloWorld.class" width="300" height ="300">
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried calling the html locally on my pc and also uploaded the .java, .class and .html file to my web site and I get the following error Error: Click for details in a box

see link below
http://www.airandcore.com/HelloWorld.html

I am using jdk1.7.0_51 and have jre7 installed and verified

Any advice or answers will be gratefully received, I have waded through the internet for 3 days :-(

Comment: It works for [Iced Tea](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/icedtea/) though.

Comment: Well? What happened when you clicked for details?

Comment: @Me_JF It is an open source version of Java generally used on *nix systems.

Comment: Click for Details, Application Blocked by Security Settings, (Details, Ignore or Reload Buttons)  I click Details and I get a Java console box Java Plug-in 10.51.2.13
Using JRE version 1.7.0_51-b13 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Documents and Settings\Julia
.....

    I have Java Plug (Java(TM) Platform SE 7 U51 10.51.2.13) set to always activate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your applet is not signed. Since Java 1.7 u51 oracle blocks unsigned (or signed with untrusted certificates) applets completely. To make sure this is not the problem, go with an older Java Version, e.g. some 1.6 er version.

Here is oracles manual for applet signing: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/security/rsa_signing.html. But to get a trusted certificate you have to invest money.

Comment: I will try that now, thanks, How do I sign an applet?

Comment: Thank you so much, I now need to find out how to sign Applets so I can use the newer version.

Answer (score -1):

try this it works perfectly

```
.class

import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends Applet{
   public void paint(Graphics g){
      g.drawString("Welcome in Java Applet.",40,20);
   }
}

.html

<HTML>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div >
<APPLET CODE="Main.class" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="500">
</APPLET>
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: the file name should be same as class name(like Main.java)

Comment: I tried that and when I run it locally I get Application Blocked by Security Settings, I click ok and get the same error as before, I have Java Plug (Java(TM) Platform SE 7 U51 10.51.2.13) set to always activate!

Comment: check u have only one version or any other ,i think u have another java version in your system ,set the class path manually in command prompt and compile

Comment: Thanks, bharat. but i've checked that, I only have version 7 installed, I can't run your example from command prompt I get the following error Error: Main method not found in class HelloWorld, please define the main method
as:
   public static void main(String[] args)  I have been able to run other simple java programs from the command line - but can't get any to work on my local or online web site!

Comment: u r writing applet program so u just compile and it generates .class file,if u run like java Main its wrong because jvm expected main method so u will get error as u got.so use that generated class file like <APPLET CODE="Main.class" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="500">.make sure both files(main.class file and .html file)in same folder